# bank account program using aspectj

Tags: java, aspectj

I want to write a java program that would keep track of a bank account

right now I have the following simple program:

```
public class account
{
    private double balance;
    private String owner;
    public account(double x, String s) { balance=x; owner=s; }
    public String owner() { return owner; }
    public void withdraw(double a) { balance -= a; }
    public void deposit(double a) { balance += a; }
    public void printbalance() { System.out.println(balance); }

    // main for testing:
public static void main(String[] argv)
{
      account a1 = new account(2000,"you boss");
      account a2 = new account(1000,"me nerd");
      a1.deposit(400);
      a2.withdraw(300000);   // not enough money!
      a2.withdraw(-500000); // trying to cheat!
      a1.printbalance();
      a2.printbalance();
}//main
} // account
```

And I want to add to this program using aspectj the following:

1- I want to prevent the account from withdraw a greater amount of the current balance and withdraw a negative numbers.

2- also I want it to prevent deposit a negative numbers.

3- I need to add a graphical interface , (buttons )

4- add secret pin or password that needs to be entered before a customer can make transaction.

5- keep track of all the transactions (withdraws and deposits) made on an account, and print out a report when asked for.

I would appreciate your help. Thank you.

```
privileged aspect newAccount
{
  //withdraw (prevent withdraw negative numbers and number greater than the   //current balance) 
    void around(account a, double x) : execution(void account.withdraw(double)) && target(a) && args(x){
        if(x > a.balance){
            System.out.println("not enough money!");
            return;
        }else if(x < 0){
            System.out.println("trying to cheat!");
            return;
        }
        proceed(a, x);
    }

//Deposit: prevent deposit negative number
    void around(double x) : execution(void account.deposit(double)) && args(x){
        if(x < 0){
            System.out.println("trying to  deposit negtive money!");
            return;
        }
        proceed(x);
    } 

    after() : execution(public static void *.main(String[])){
        account.a3 = new account(3000,"he nerd");
        a3.deposit(-100);
        a3.printbalance();

    }

//To Do: pin secret password 
//To Do: Transaction Record
}
```

Comment: 1, 2 and to a degree 4 & 5 could be done better without AOP. I have no idea how AspectJ could be of any use for 3. If you just want to practice with AspectJ, there are some examples in the [official documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/) that could get you started.

Comment: I disagree. I would exclude 3 because a GUI is not an aspect. But 1, 2, 4, 5 can be implemented via AOP (of course also without). As for the GUI, maybe the communication (notifications, events) between GUI and back-end could also be done via AOP. But let's skip the opinionated discussion and cut to the chase: Am I correctly assuming that this is some kind of homework assignment and the whole point of it is to use AOP?

Comment: yes, most of it. @kriegaex

Comment: So what have you tried and where is your problem? Show some aspect code, please. Or did you expect someone here to completely do your homework assignment for you? You can pay me to do that, but I have this feeling that you would rather want information for free, optimally without doing any work by yourself.

Comment: I added what I have done so far. Sorry for inconvenience. I Just want to understand the aspectj since I'm still learning Java. I would appreciate any help. Thank You. @kriegaex

Comment: Thanks for the update. By chance, today there was [another AspectJ question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61429008/1082681) related to an bank account example. Is this guy your co-student? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you are still learning Java because you don't know the basic programming conventions such as that

- class names should start with an upper case letter,
- variables, parameters and fields should have understandable names not not single letters.

You are also using direct field access from a privileged aspect instead of just creating public getter methods for your class's fields and using those. A `toString` method is also helpful because then you can easily print the object without accessing getters and fabricating your own output.

Besides, the advice running after the `main` method is a nice experiment but does not make make much sense. Because the account owner has the same name as one of the account owners in your application, it looks as if you want to hack into that account. I commented the code there so as to explain why it cannot work like that.

I also refactored both your application class and the aspect to now look like this without changing the functionality:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Account {
  private String owner;
  private double balance;

  public Account(String owner, double balance) {
    this.owner = owner;
    this.balance = balance;
  }

  public void withdraw(double amount) {
    balance -= amount;
  }

  public void deposit(double amount) {
    balance += amount;
  }

  public String getOwner() {
    return owner;
  }

  public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Account[owner=" + owner + ", balance=" + balance + "]";
  }

  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    Account bossAccount = new Account("Boss", 2000);
    Account nerdAccount = new Account("Nerd", 1000);
    bossAccount.deposit(400);
    nerdAccount.withdraw(200);
    bossAccount.withdraw(300000);    // Cannot withdraw more than account balance
    nerdAccount.withdraw(-500000);   // Cannot withdraw a negative amount
    bossAccount.deposit(-123456);    // Cannot deposit a negative amount
    System.out.println(bossAccount);
    System.out.println(nerdAccount);
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.Account;

public aspect AccountAspect {

  // Withdrawal
  void around(Account account, double amount) :
    execution(void Account.withdraw(double)) &&
    target(account) &&
    args(amount)
  {
    if (amount > account.getBalance()) {
      System.out.println("Cannot withdraw more than account balance");
      return;
    }
    if (amount < 0) {
      System.out.println("Cannot withdraw a negative amount");
      return;
    }
    proceed(account, amount);
  }

  // Deposit
  void around(double amount) :
    execution(void Account.deposit(double)) &&
    args(amount)
  {
    if (amount < 0) {
      System.out.println("Cannot deposit a negative amount");
      return;
    }
    proceed(amount);
  }

  // This does not make any sense because
  //   1. it happens after the application ends (after leaving main method)
  //   2. Even though the account owner is the same as in the main method,
  //      it does not mean that by creating a new object with the same name
  //      the "Nerd" can manipulate the original account balance. You have to
  //      intercept the original Account object and manipulate it directly.
  after() : execution(public static void *.main(String[])) {
    System.out.println("--- after end of main program ---");
    Account account = new Account("Nerd", 3000);
    account.deposit(-100);
    System.out.println(account);
  }

  // TODO: PIN secret password
  // TODO: transaction record
}
```

The console log will be:

```
Cannot withdraw more than account balance
Cannot withdraw a negative amount
Cannot deposit a negative amount
Account[owner=Boss, balance=2400.0]
Account[owner=Nerd, balance=800.0]
--- after end of main program ---
Cannot deposit a negative amount
Account[owner=Nerd, balance=3000.0]
```

I will not do your homework assignment for you, but give you some hints:

- PIN (secret password): The `Account` class needs a field `pin` which could be set in a constructor and should not have a public getter method in order to avoid that anyone can access the PIN. If the assignment requires you not to edit the base class but solve the problem via AOP, you can use inter-type definition (ITD) in order to add a private field and a public setter, maybe even an additional constructor to the class. Next you would add an advice which would ask the user to enter a PIN on the console if he tries to access any transactional methods such as `deposit` and `withdraw` of a certain account for the first time. After entering the PIN correctly he would be able to continue, otherwise there would be an error message and the transaction would be forbidden. The aspect itself could keep a cache (temporary storage) of all `Account` objects - probably you want to use a `Set<Account>` - which have been successfully authenticated during the running session, so as to avoid that the user has to enter the PIN for the same account again.
- Transaction record per account: Again, you can use ITD in order to add something like a `List<TransactionRecord>` as a field to the `Account`, initialise it with an empty list and then add a transaction record for each deposit or withdrawal. You can also keep it simple for your proof of concept, not creating a `TransactionRecord` helper class but just using a `List<Double>` for the transactions, recording positive amounts for deposits and negative ones for withdrawals. A `List<String>` with elements like "deposit 123.45" or "withdrawal 67.89" is also a viable alternative. The important thing is that your teacher can see the correct aspect logic.